# jqGrid + bootstrap-multiselect visibility issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqgrid, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using jqGrid 5.0.1 and trying to implement custom filter for column with [bootstrap -multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/).
It looks like there is some conflict in CSS with jQgrid, because I can see the default value or programmatically selected one, but when I click on the filter I don't see dropdown. With inspector it appear to be working but it's just not visible..some overflow or z-index bug. Can any one help me out with this ?

```
    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        url: 'assets/static_data/data.json',
        //mtype: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        styleUI: 'Bootstrap',
        //shrinkToFit: true,
        multiselect: true, // column with checkboxes
        autowidth: true,
        colNames: ['Order ID', 'Ship Name', 'Freight'],
        colModel: [
            {
                //sorttype: 'integer',
                name: 'OrderID',
                key: true,
                width: 75,
                editable: true,
            },
            {
                name: 'ShipName',
                width: 150,
                stype: "select",

                searchoptions: {

                    // dataInit is the client-side event that fires upon initializing the toolbar search field for a column
                    // use it to place a third party control to customize the toolbar
                    dataInit: function (element) {

                        console.log(element);
                        var options = [
                            {label: 'Option 1', title: 'Option 1', value: '1'},
                            {label: 'Option 2', title: 'Option 2', value: '2'},
                            {label: 'Option 3', title: 'Option 3', value: '3', selected: true},
                            {label: 'Option 4', title: 'Option 4', value: '4'},
                            {label: 'Option 5', title: 'Option 5', value: '5'},
                            {label: 'Option 6', title: 'Option 6', value: '6'}
                        ];

                        $(element).multiselect('dataprovider', options);
                        //$(element).multiselect('setOptions', options);
                        //$(element).multiselect('rebuild');
                    },
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'Freight',
                sorttype: 'number',
                width: 150
            },

        ],
        loadonce: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        width: 780,
        height: 250,
        rowNum: 10,
        pager: "#jqGridPager",

    }); // end jqGrid
```

Comment: I never used bootstrap-multiselect, but used Erichynd's multiselect with JQGrid and it worked nice. You may want to see an example [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/MultiselectIn.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
multiselect : true,
multiselectWidth : 50
```

Comment: this is more like a comment than an answer, please elaborate your answer